# iOS12: UIWebView problems

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios12

Our app uses intensely UIWebView for login and downloading of stuff from intranet portals. However immediately with the upgrade it stopped working since as far as I have found out, our previously used method webviewDidFinishLoad gets called, however a necessary distinction we have by using if(webview.isLoading) return; always stops the execution. So somehow since iOS 12 the webview doesn't stop loading content..or the variable isn't set. Any idea why?

And I've read UIWebView is deprecated now and you should use WKWebView. But as far as I understand I cannot simply switch and all the same methods exists, but it is much more complicated than that?

Comment: check this out https://nshipster.com/wkwebview/